# Got error as TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    myList= list(line.split("|"))
    temp=list(myList(0).split(" "))
    list1=()
    list2=()
    newList=()
    for ele in temp:
        if ele.strip():
            list1.append(ele)
    temp=list(mylist(1).split(" "))
    for ele in temp:
        if ele.strip():
            list2.append(ele.strip())
    count=0
    for count in range (len(list1)):      
        newList.append(int(list1(count))*int(list2(count)))
        count=count+1
    print(newList)
```

I am trying to print the multiplied list.

Test 1 Input
9 0 6 | 15 14 9
Expected Output
135 0 54

Test 2
13 4 15 1 15 5 | 1 4 15 14 8 2
Expected Output
13 16 225 14 120 10

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+python+list+object+is+not+callable) of [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable while trying to access a list](/q/5735841/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

Access list elements by index, so change the `mylist(1)` to `mylist[1]`
And i fixed your code like this

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    myList = line.split("|")
    list1, list2, newList = [], [], []

    for ele in myList[0].split(" "):
        if ele.strip():
            list1.append(ele)

    for ele in myList[1].split(" "):
        if ele.strip():
            list2.append(ele.strip())

    for index in range(len(list1)):
        newList.append(int(list1[index]) * int(list2[index]))
    print(" ".join(str(i) for i in newList))
```

Comment: File "/tmp/source.py", line 8, in <module>
    temp=list(myList(0).split(" "))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @Chan `myList(0)` change it to!

Comment: My output comes with comma [135, 0, 54]

Comment: @Chan Yes, that’s a list. It’s not an output “with comma”. Learn how to convert a list into the data type expected by the test.

Comment: @Chan print by `print(" ".join(str(i) for i in newList))`